# Compare numbers in two strings in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having two strings as @CountryLocationIDs and @LocationIDs with values:

```
@CountryLocationIDs = 400,600,150,850,160,250
@LocationIDs1       = 600,150,900
```

Then I need the output in another variable as:

```
@LocationIDs = 400,600,150,850,160,250,900
```

Anybody please help out... Thanks in advance...

Comment: It looks as if you are paying the price for denormalisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created table-valued function which accepts two parameters, first is string with IDs, and second is delimiter in string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items nvarchar(4000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice nvarchar(4000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

After creating function, just use `UNION` set operator on this way:

**EDITED**

```
WITH ListCTE AS 
(
select items from dbo.split('400,600,150,850,160,250', ',')
union
select items from dbo.split('600,150,900', ',')
)
SELECT TOP 1

   MemberList = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + items )
                           FROM ListCTE t2
                           ORDER BY 
                              items
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 3, 1000 )FROM ListCTE t1
```

With `UNION` you will automatically get distinct values from both strings, so you don't need to use `DISTINCT` clause

Comment: I need to save tis output in a varchar variable... While trying to store, I am getting the error as : Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetDLMembersByListType1, Line 51
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: SET @Location_IDs = ((select * from dbo.SplitString(@CountryLocation_IDs, ',')) union (select * from dbo.SplitString(@Location_IDs, ',')))

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use option with dynamic management function [sys.dm_fts_parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
Before script execution you need check full-text component is installed:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY ('IsFulltextInstalled')
```

0 = Full-text is not installed. 1 = Full-text is installed. NULL = Invalid input, or error.

If 0 = Full-text is not installed then this post is necessary to you [How to install fulltext on sql server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869736/how-to-install-fulltext-on-sql-server-2008)

```
DECLARE @CountryLocationIDs nvarchar(100) = '400,600,150,850,160,250',
        @LocationIDs1       nvarchar(100) = '600,150,900',
        @LocationIDs        nvarchar(100) = N''

SELECT @LocationIDs += display_term + ','
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"'+ 'nn,' + @CountryLocationIDs + ',' + @LocationIDs1 + '"', 1033, NULL, 0)  
WHERE display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%'
GROUP BY display_term

SELECT LEFT(@LocationIDs, LEN(@LocationIDs) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html) will help you through programming

and you may also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127384/built-in-support-for-sets-in-php)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here. What if the page(s) you've linked to are moved or deleted? It would be a lot more helpful to include a summary to what you're linking to.